# Login system in python . Show usersInfo.update({line[0]: line[1]}) IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to create a login system that reads username and password from the text. But now it shows an index out of range. I cannot understand CZ I am new to the python language.

```
def login():

    print("welcome to User Login !")
    print("---------")
    usersInfo = {}
    with open('userInfo.txt','r') as file :
        for line in file :
            line= line.split()
            usersInfo.update({line[0]: line[1]})
    while True:
        userName = input("Enter your name: ").title()
        userName = sanitizename(userName)
        if userName not in usersInfo:
            print("You are Not registered")
            print()
        else:
            break

    while True:
        userPassword = input("Enter your password:")
        if not (userPassword,usersInfo[userName]):
            print("Incorrect password")
        else:
            break

    print()
    print("Successfully Logged in !")
```

[image]

Comment: What are the contents of `userInfo.txt`?

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code defines a function and quits without calling it.

Comment: We expect you to at least look up the error message and try to trace the offending values within your program.  "I cannot understand CZ [because?] I am new to the python language" is false.  Being new just means you have more to learn.  The meaning of the error message is simple to look up, and many explanations come with how to diagnose and fix the problems.  We expect you to finish this before you post here.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: def addUserInfo(userInfo: list):
    with open('userInfo.txt','a') as file :
        for info in userInfo:
            file.write(info)
            file.write(' ')
        file.write('\n')

Comment: You can [edit] the question with new information. Don't use comments. Anyway we need a [mre] of the file you're reading

Answer (score 0):

There is a line in `userInfo.txt` that does not have a username and a password.

Maybe it has only a username, maybe it has only a password, or maybe it is just a blank line (i.e. just a newline character).

On such a line, `.split()` will return a list with less than two items, so `line[1]` is out of bounds.

Edit your file and fix/remove the bad line(s).

Comment: In userInfo.txt, I have included these 
Naim 78742 
Naim naim 
Mir-Naim